# How to partition a RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, partitioning, apache-spark, rdd

I have a text file consisting of a large number of random floating values separated by spaces.
I am loading this file into a RDD in scala. 
How does this RDD get partitioned?

Also, is there any method to generate custom partitions such that all partitions have equal number of elements along with an index for each partition?

```
val dRDD = sc.textFile("hdfs://master:54310/Data/input*")
keyval=dRDD.map(x =>process(x.trim().split(' ').map(_.toDouble),query_norm,m,r))
```

Here I am loading multiple text files from HDFS and process is a function I am calling.
Can I have a solution with mapPartitonsWithIndex along with how can I access that index inside the process function? Map shuffles the partitions.

Comment: You have 3 answers, aren't you going to accept/comment one? :)

Answer (score 3):

> How does an RDD gets partitioned?

By default a partition is created for each HDFS partition, which by default is 64MB. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368362/how-does-partitioning-work-in-spark).

> How to balance my data across partitions?

First, take a look at the three ways one can *repartition* his data:

1) Pass a second parameter, the desired *minimum* number of partitions
    for your RDD, into [textFile()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=textfile#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile), but be careful:

```
In [14]: lines = sc.textFile("data")

In [15]: lines.getNumPartitions()
Out[15]: 1000

In [16]: lines = sc.textFile("data", 500)

In [17]: lines.getNumPartitions()
Out[17]: 1434

In [18]: lines = sc.textFile("data", 5000)

In [19]: lines.getNumPartitions()
Out[19]: 5926
```

As you can see, `[16]` doesn't do what one would expect, since the number of partitions the RDD has, is already greater than the minimum number of partitions we request.

2) Use [repartition()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=repartition#pyspark.RDD.repartition), like this:

```
In [22]: lines = lines.repartition(10)

In [23]: lines.getNumPartitions()
Out[23]: 10
```

Warning: This will invoke a shuffle and should be used when you want to **increase** the number of partitions your RDD has.

From the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations):

> The shuffle is Spark’s mechanism for re-distributing data so that it’s grouped differently across partitions. This typically involves copying data across executors and machines, making the shuffle a complex and costly operation.

3) Use [coalesce()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=coalesce#pyspark.RDD.coalesce), like this:

```
In [25]: lines = lines.coalesce(2)

In [26]: lines.getNumPartitions()
Out[26]: 2
```

Here, Spark knows that you will shrink the RDD and gets advantage of it. Read more about [repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce).

---

But will all this **guarantee** that your data will be perfectly balanced across your partitions? Not really, as I experienced in [How to balance my data across the partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799753/how-to-balance-my-data-across-the-partitions)

Answer (score 2):

The loaded rdd is partitioned by default partitioner: hash code. To specify custom partitioner, use can check rdd.partitionBy(), provided with your own partitioner.

I don't think it's ok to use coalesce() here, as by api docs, coalesce() can only be used when we reduce number of partitions, and even we can't specify a custom partitioner with coalesce().

Answer (score 1):

You can generate custom partitions using the coalesce function:

```
coalesce(numPartitions: Int, shuffle: Boolean = false): RDD[T]
```

Comment: What about an index? How will I be able to access that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question regarding the index, but you can you the mapPartitionsWithIndex function

Comment: Basically when I divide my RDD I would like to be able to access an index corresponding to each partition. I tried mapPartitonsWithIndex, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide your code. Nomally it should work. here is an example of how it is used.
val partRdd = partitionedRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(a =>  (a._1(this is the index), a._2)