# Difference in default partitioning by instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My understanding was that spark will choose the 'default' number of partitions, solely based on the size of the file or if its a union of many parquet files, the number of parts.

However, in reading in a set of large parquet files, I see the that default # of partitions for an EMR cluster with a single d2.2xlarge is ~1200.  However, in a cluster of 2 r3.8xlarge I'm getting default partitions of ~4700.

What metrics does Spark use to determine the default partitions?

EMR 5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

> spark.default.parallelism - **Default number of partitions** in RDDs returned by transformations like join, reduceByKey, and parallelize when not set by user.
>
> 2X number of CPU cores available to YARN containers.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html#spark-defaults

[Looks like it matches non EMR/AWS Spark as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368362/how-does-partitioning-work-in-spark#26368801)

Comment: I think that only applies for when you do something like sc.parallelize(<collection>), not when you're reading from s3.  Or, if a single file is large, it'll split that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some transient issue because I restarted that EMR cluster with d2.2xlarge and it gave me the number of partitions I expected, which matched the r3.8xlarge, which was the number of files on s3.

If anyone knows why this kind of things happens though, I'll gladly mark yours as the answer.